# what to do for the bad quality of jspdf?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, jspdf, html2canvas

I used Html2canvas and jspdf to make a pdf of a webpage.
why jspdf make bad quality pdf how can i fix it ? 
It's so important for me ! 
is there some options to add to addImage() to fix it ? or something else ... !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, solved by adopting the new html2canvas.js 1.0.0-alpha.11 instead of html2canvas 0.5.0-beta4. Not sure about which version you are using.